Is adultery of the heart the same as committing adultery in the flesh?
There are some who take Matthew 5:28 where Christ speaks of adultery of the heart as true physical adultery and thus grounds for divorce.
I think this is a heart issue as noted in the context of the entire 5th chapter. Clearly lusting after a woman is a sin yet does it rise to the level of true physical adultery which may be grounds for New Testament divorce.
I am looking for input on this issue.
“But I tell you that anyone who looks at a woman lustfully has already committed adultery with her in his heart.”
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭5‬:‭28‬ ‭NIV‬‬
https://bible.com/bible/111/mat.5.28.NIV

Where in Scripture is adultery permitted as grounds for divorce? Are you thinking of Matthew 5:32 / Matthew 19:9? Because those don't mention adultery, but "sexual immorality" (frequently used as a euphemism for homosexuality and other such perversions). That suggests not mere "wandering" (i.e. not even physical adultery), but a compromised ability (or willingness) to engage in normal sexual relations. IOW, not permission to dissolve a marriage "because we don't love each other any more", or even because a spouse has sinned, but to dissolve a marriage beyond hope of functioning as intended.

In any case, what's the actual Question? The answer to "is adultery of the heart the same as committing adultery in the flesh?" would clearly seem to be "yes" on the basis of Matthew 5:28. However, the body of your Question mentions grounds for divorce, which is either irrelevant, or the subject of your actual inquiry.

I think it reasonable to take all of Matthew 5 as primarily describing an individual's position under the judgement of a righteous God who looks not only on the outward appearance but on the heart as well.  The same God who can rightly judge whether an action is of faith or not, can discern and judge according to intentions of the heart.
The sections of chapter 5 stretching from verse 21 through to the end of the chapter all follow the same pattern:  "You have heard it said, but I say.".  That is, the Lord Jesus reminds of a command from God given to regulate and condemn individual behavior and then He deepens the teaching to also include related matters of the heart.
To be angry with a brother without a cause is to be in danger of the judgement of murder (vs.21-22).  Obviously this condition of the heart is not subject to human jurisprudence.
To lust after a woman in heart is adultery already (v. 28).  Once again, no human court of Law could prove and convict the internal machinations of the heart.
What is in view is not interpersonal human judgements but Divine judgement.  Therefore adultery of the heart is the same as adultery in the flesh before the Living God but not in the eyes of men (who cannot see the heart).  The repercussions of the wicked heart are given in the very next verses and they do not speak of human judgement.

And if thy right eye offend thee, pluck it out, and cast it from thee: for it is profitable for thee that one of thy members should perish, and not that thy whole body should be cast into hell. And if thy right hand offend thee, cut it off, and cast it from thee: for it is profitable for thee that one of thy members should perish, and not that thy whole body should be cast into hell. - Matthew 5:29-30


The question is in some ways absurd but in some ways rather important.  It queries into the Biblical concept of sin in contrast with Civil law concept of crime and highlights the difference between the two.
In our natural standing before God we are all adulterous, idol worshipers and filled with murder, as the flesh is filled with sensual lust, greed and anger. However such dead people can seem externally pure like a whitewashed tomb.
Likewise, a person may fail outwardly and even be charged with a crime and then put in prison, but he/she may be inwardly holy just as Christ was put to death by the religious leaders.
The simple answer under this obvious dichotomy is that lusting and committing external adultery are the same in essence but widely different in the law, created by God to govern the world in external matters by the sword for the sake of external peace.
The reason why the law can’t really govern the State like the gospel governs the Church is that it is not designed to know the heart and must judge on external appearances utilizing external testimonies and evidence.
When it comes to external adultery Civil law should provide the legal means for divorce.  Guessing internally some level of desire to be the basis of a law or to apply the law would be completely impractical and impossible without the infinite knowledge of God himself who alone is capable to judge spiritually.
Similarly, if the State were to arrest every person who had an angry thought or who exhibited a certain level of anger, and on that basis charge them with murder, it would be entirely implausible and impractical to govern the world this way.
In the Church the gospel governs not through the sword but by faith and requires a much greater holiness than mere conformance to external rules.
In conclusion, internal and external sins are similar in being rooted in the heart but they have completely different social consequences before man and the agreements and contracts they may enter into with one another.

Great answer as it provides an illustration of why the Lutheran style "Law and Gospel" dichotomy is so important to Luther and useful as a principle to cleanly separate the legal vs. spiritual application of the Law (in its myriad expressions within the separate realms of State vs. Church), so even those (like me), who disagree with Luther in his opinion regarding the nature of sin as you described in your other answer, can appreciate this dichotomy.

@GratefulDisciple - Yes this is very much the way Luther would divide it. It is correct to describe it as Lutheran. Your ability to understand someone you disagree with is admirable.
